# Can you index an array with a binary number in C?

Tags: c

I was wondering if it is possible to index an array by using a binary number instead of a decimal number. For instance, arr[binary].

Comment: On a computer, all numbers are binary. You'll need to be more specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Numbers in C source code can be written in octal, decimal, or hexadecimal, but not binary. (I suppose binary literals might've been added very recently, but if so, I haven't heard about it.)

Comment: As @zwol said, not directly, but you can write a function that converts a string representing a binary number to an integer. Then, you can say `arr[binary_to_int(binary)]`

Answer (score 2):

Yep that's definitely possible. Just prepend your binary number with 0b

```c
int array[] = {1,2,4,6};
printf("%d\n", array[0b0001]); // prints 2
```

from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html binary constants can be written using the 0b syntax

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a source that describes this syntax?

Comment: I wonder how many compilers support this syntax. I'm not able to find many references to it, and I just confirmed C# doesn't support it.

Comment: I used gcc running on a mac to compile, i've also used this syntax on on PIC microprocessors using MPLABx and the C18 compiler.

Comment: This appears to have been added to GCC in version [4.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html) (search for "binary" - sadly, there are no #anchors).  The [feature request for it](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23479) says "This is a frequently requested item in microcontroller environments, and several other compilers already implement it."  But it doesn't say which other compilers those are.  Also, as of C11, this is still an extension, not an official part of the language.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, all numbers stored on a computer are binary. Binary is the *only* thing that can be stored on a computer.

And, C does not support binary syntax. (Or perhaps come C compilers do?)

You could however convert a string from binary like this:

```
var value = arr[BinaryToInt("1011")];

int BinaryToInt(string s)
{
    int value = 0;
    int bitValue = 1;

    for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s[i] == '1')
            value += bitValue;

        bitValue <<= 1;
    }
    return value;
}
```